# What does "counter-reasoning" exactly mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

What does "counter-reasoning" exactly mean? 
I have got trouble finding its meaning in the web or in a dictionary.

Comment: It is reasoning that counters or goes against other reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the "[Harvard College Writing Center](http://writingcenter.fas.harvard.edu/pages/counter-argument)"

> When you write an academic essay, you make an argument: you propose a thesis and offer some reasoning, using evidence, that suggests why the thesis is true. When you counter-argue, you consider a possible argument against your thesis or some aspect of your reasoning...
>   it can be a persuasive and (in both senses of the word) disarming tactic. It allows you to anticipate doubts and pre-empt objections that a skeptical reader might have

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterargument#):

> ... a counter argument is **an objection to an objection**

The same source gives this useful schematic (Graham's Hierarchy of Disagreement):

[image]

EDIT: I’ve just realised that I haven’t used the exact phrase **counter-reasoning**. The explanation involving these exact words is difficult to come by on the internet. To support the claim that the above does answer the question:

[Counter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counter) (as an adjective) MW defines as:

> marked by or tending toward or in an opposite direction or effect

There are not many examples of usage (about 825 on Google Books, and some false positive), but [this example](https://books.google.rs/books?id=JU8oAAAAQBAJ&pg=PR18&dq=%22counter-reasoning%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nQg6VdWxKuXMyAO474HICQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22counter-reasoning%22&f=false) conveys the same meaning for *counter-reasoning* as the term *counter-argument* (explained above). It is a note in a translation of Plato’s Protagoras talking about Bonitz using counter-reasoning by Socrates as a proof of a certain statement being refuted. It’s the most direct explanation I managed to dig up.